# Remove font size in TinyMCE

Tags: fonts, tinymce, font-size

How can I remove certain font size options from the font size selector in TinyMCE?

Regards
Johan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question.

You can select which font sizes you want to include with the *theme_advanced_font_sizes* option. I.e theme_advanced_font_sizes : "1,2,4,7"